# Why does Primary Node respond twice for worker message?

Tags: node.js, http, multiprocessing

I tried to make server that spawns workers to do tasks and send resoults to primary node to use resoults as response but when I was finding a way to make primary node comunicate with workers I found that primary node responds twice to worker messages.

Btw listening to workers outside server function didn't work for me.

code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 3000;
var path = require('path');
var cluster = require('cluster');
const totalCPUs = require("os").availableParallelism();

function color(style, foreground, background){
    return `\x1b[${style};${foreground};${background}m`
}

function x1b(foreground){
    return `\x1b[${foreground}m`
}

function resetc(){
    return '\x1b[0m'
}

if (cluster.isPrimary){
    const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        if (req.url === "/setcookie"){
            var cookie = {
                username: "",
                hashedpassword: "",
                status: "NotLogedIn"
            };
            res.writeHead(200, {'Set-Cookie': JSON.stringify(cookie), 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end();
        }
        
        else if (req.url === "/js/getuserdata"){
            console.log(`[${x1b(32)}request${resetc()}][${x1b(33)}js${resetc()}]: requested user data for user ${req.headers.cookie ? `'${(JSON.parse(req.headers.cookie)).username}'` : "*null*"}`);
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
            res.end(req.headers.cookie);
        }
        
        else if(req.url === "/test"){
            worker = cluster.fork();
            worker.send({
                work: "test"
            });
            res.end();
        }
        
        else if(req.url === "/" || req.url === "/index.html"){
            fs.readFile("./src/index.html", "UTF-8", function(err, html){
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                res.end(html);
                console.log(`[${x1b(32)}request${resetc()}]: A user has visited this site`);
            });
        }
        else {
            var dotoffset = req.url.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (dotoffset != -1){
                var mime = dotoffset == -1
                                ? ['text/plain', "UTF-8"]
                                : ({
                                    '.html' : ['text/html', null],
                                    '.ico' : ['image/x-icon', null],
                                    '.jpg' : ['image/jpeg', null],
                                    '.png' : ['image/png', null],
                                    '.svg' : ['image/svg+xml', null],
                                    '.gif' : ['image/gif', null],
                                    '.ogg' : ['sound/ogg', null],
                                    '.css' : ['text/css', "UTF-8"],
                                    '.js' : ['text/javascript', "UTF-8"]
                                    }[ req.url.substring(dotoffset) ]
                                ? {
                                    '.html' : ['text/html', null],
                                    '.ico' : ['image/x-icon', null],
                                    '.jpg' : ['image/jpeg', null],
                                    '.png' : ['image/png', null],
                                    '.svg' : ['image/svg+xml', null],
                                    '.gif' : ['image/gif', null],
                                    '.ogg' : ['sound/ogg', null],
                                    '.css' : ['text/css', "UTF-8"],
                                    '.js' : ['text/javascript', "UTF-8"]
                                    }[ req.url.substring(dotoffset) ]
                                :   ['text/plain', "UTF-8"]); 

                // console.log(mime);
                if (mime[0] == 'text/html'){
                    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    fs.readFile('./' + req.url, function(err, data) {
                        if (!err) {res.end(data);}
                    });
                }
                else {
                    if (mime[1] != null){
                        var fPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src', req.url);
                        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fPath, mime[1]);
                        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": mime[0]});
                        fileStream.pipe(res);
                    } else {
                        var fPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src', req.url);
                        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fPath);
                        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": mime[0]});
                        fileStream.pipe(res);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //mark worker message handling
        for(id in cluster.workers){
            console.log(id);
            console.log(Object.keys(cluster.workers));
            cluster.workers[id].on("message", (msg) => {
                console.log(`${msg.res} ${id}`);
            })
        }
        

    })
    
    server.listen(port, function(err){
        console.log(`err: ${err}`);
    })

    

} else {
    console.log(`hej ${process.pid}`);
    process.on("message", async (msg) => {
        if (msg.work == "test"){
            console.log("WOOOOOOAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaa");
            process.send({res: "goger"});
            // process.kill(process.pid);
        }
    })
}
```

console log after going to localhost:3000/test :

- 1
- [ '1' ]
- 1
- [ '1' ]
- hej 10812
- WOOOOOOAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaa
- goger 1
- goger 1

What did you try and what were you expecting?

- That server will respond once.